# Is this the full-bridge DC-DC converter topology? What's the benefits of iso/non-iso topology?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I found a power circuit in an schematics, which looks like a full-bridge topology.
Anyone familiar with such design?
I check the websites, but didn't see the same implementation.
The pink blocks are controllers and drivers, but I can't find its datasheet also...

BTW, I have another question.
What the benefit of isolation topology over non-isolated one?
Suppose I just want to provide core for CPU on motherboard, the input is rather 12V, or 48V (server), which topology will be more suitable for my design?
I've seen that for 12V, non-isolated design will be implemented, while isolated solution be used for 48V case. Is the input power which matters?

Thannks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage of such isolation is protection of low voltage circuitry. Buck regulator can fail (some mosfet shorts) and in non-isolated topology you would pass 48V directly to low voltage side of your motherboard and fry every expensive chip. In isolated topology fried mosfet is not a problem, isolated part is safe.

Answer (score -1):

This circuit looks like high efficiency resonant isolating converter. It is appropriate for output currents 20 A or higher.

Isolated power supply is significantly more expensive and complex than non-isolating one (for the same power / current / voltage). The main reason for using isolated design for 48 V to some low output voltage is a desire to decouple from interference coming through power input. The regulation ability of isolated designs is far worse than that of non-isolated (Buck) design.

Also, you should be aware of making DC-DC converters with too high Vin/Vout ratio. Simple and cost effective Buck (step down) topology can handle Vin/Vout < 10. The duty factor becomes too small otherwise.

Therefore, you may have to consider two stage conversion.

Comment: We cannot say "resonant", because there's no series resonant capacitor. As you might guess, the resonant frequency is determined by the external inductance *(or primary leakage inductance which is kept high intentionally by transformer design)* plus primary inductance and external capacitance.